# GRUB update does not see Liquorix kernel on Ubuntu Studio

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I have linked the relevant dumps and info to: https://techpatterns.com/forums/about2838.html

The problem seems to be that Liquorix installs fine, but Grub update does not add it to the selection of kernels on the system.

Answer (score 0):

By policy, Ubuntu Studio does not allow for any kernel other than the official kernel in the Ubuntu repository. You *can* get by this by removing the ubuntustudio-lowlatency-settings package:

```
sudo apt remove ubuntustudio-lowlatency-settings
```

However, this is not recommended and not supported.